# Question about combining functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $F(1/g(x))=F(g(x))$ enough to say that $F(1/x)=F(x)$. Seems pretty reasonable but just want to make sure. Also keep in mind that I'm not worrying about domain and range of $g(x)$.

Comment: Well you need to properly fully you symbols and how you got each of them.  There is a big difference between "Let $F,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions..." and "Let $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Then for any function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be true of the range of $g$ includes all non-zero real numbers; otherwise it could be false.

Answer (score 1):

No! If e.g. $g$  is the constant function prescribed by $x\mapsto1$  then the premisse implies nothing.

From $F(1)=F(1)$  you cannot conclude that e.g. $F(\frac12 )=F(2)$.